# how to create a webview in blackberry which allows me to only view the page and disable all other options

Tags: blackberry-webworks

How to create a webview which gives me only option of viewing the webpage and the rest of the options should be disabled.
BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
        browserSession.displayPage("http://www.google.co.in/");
I tried this code but not able to disable the options in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the wrong tag of 'blackberry-webworks' for your post, sounds like a Java question?

In any event...  BlackBerry WebWorks is essentially a webapp/webpage running natively on a device.

If you were to use WebWorks for development, you would simply create a webpage (html, css, javascript), and create a config.xml file which tells the SDK what your app is, what it wants access to do on the device, and request needed permissions, etc.

Once packaged, your app would run like any other app on the device.  The cool thing about WebWorks is technically you can create a launcher for a website.  It again would look like any other app, have it's own icon, and launch in it's own webview.  You wouldn't have any of the browser address bars, or anything like that, so this may be the way to go.

If you want some 'Getting Started' info, check-out the [HTML5 WebWorks webpage](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/what_is_a_webworks_app_1845471_11.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response but i need to make a webview for my application which only displays the webpage and disables all other options .the above code is only loading a webpage but not disabling the options.Please ehlp me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It may help somebody

```
        BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
        add(browserField);
        browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.co.in");
```